# How to count the number of instances of a particular class in inheritance tree, created explicitly?

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance

```
class A { 
    static int i;
    {
        System.out.println("A init block"+ ++i);
    }

}
class B extends A {
    static int j;
    {
        System.out.println("B init block"+ ++j);
    }
}
class C extends B {
    static int k;
    {
        System.out.println("C init block"+ ++k);
    }
        public static void main(String abc[])
        {
          C c =new C();
        }
}
```

In the code above, we can easily count the number of objects created for each class.
But if i want to check the number of object created explicitly ,  i mean if I create C's object using new C(), or B's object using new B(), then it should give the count accordingly

Take for example,

```
C c2=new C();
B b2=new B();
```

So it should give the output of B's count as 1 and not 2.

Comment: keep a static int field.. increment its count in the constructor...

Comment: @TheLostMind That static field will be incremented each time we create an object of its sub class,

Comment: well.. then decrement it in the child class constructor...

Comment: @TheLostMind :Decrementing that in child class tends to high coupling design. Dependency will increase.

Comment: @hemkaran_raghav - ya.. I agree... I think JB Nizet's answer fixes that problem...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class Foo {
    private static int fooCount = 0;

    public Foo() {
        if (this.getClass() == Foo.class) {
            fooCount++;
        }
    }

    public static int getFooCount() {
        return fooCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the need of checking `this.getClass() == Foo.class` ?

Comment: If you don't fooCount will be incremented when a subclass of Foo is instantiated, since the subclass constructor always calls the superclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    static int count;

    Test() {
        count++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();
        Test t1 = new Test();
        NewTest nt = new NewTest();
        System.out.println("Test Count : " + Test.count);
        System.out.println("NewTest Count : " + NewTest.count);
    }
}


class NewTest extends Test
{    static int count;
    NewTest()
    {
            Test.count--;
            NewTest.count++;
    }

}
```

OP :

```
Test Count : 2
NewTest Count : 1
```

Comment: I believe this produces negative values for `Test Count` if number of `NewTest` instances is larger than number of `Test` instances.