# How to sum the number of instances of an object in Java?

Tags: java, object

Right now I'm working on a basic java program that takes a few parameters into a constructor for a cup of coffee. That is easy enough but I'm having trouble creating a method for summing the number of coffee cups I've created.

So far this is the UseCoffee class I've created:

```
public class UsesCoffee{ 
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("cups created: " + Coffee.totalCups());

    Coffee cup1 = new Coffee(350, "mint", true);
    System.out.println("cup1: " + cup1);
    Coffee cup2 = new Coffee(500, "mocha", false);
    System.out.println("cups created: " + Coffee.totalCups());
    System.out.println("cup2: " + cup2);
    Coffee cup3 = new Coffee(350, "no flavour used", false);
    cup3.doubleSize();
    System.out.println("cup3: " + cup3);

    Coffee cup4 = new Coffee(-10, "mocha", false);
    System.out.println("cup4: " + cup4);

    System.out.println("cups created: " + Coffee.totalCups());

    if (Coffee.bigger(cup3,cup2))
    System.out.println("cup3 is bigger than cup2");

    if (Coffee.bigger(cup1,cup2))
    System.out.println("cup1 is bigger than cup3");

  if (Coffee.bigger(cup1,cup1))
  System.out.println("cup1 is bigger than itself");
 } // end main
} // end UsesCoffee
```

And this is the Coffee Class I've created:

```
public class Coffee {
    private int coffeeVol;
    private String coffeeFlav;
    private boolean yesCream;

    public Coffee(int volume, String flavour, boolean cream) {
        this.coffeeFlav = flavour;
        this.coffeeVol = volume;
        this.yesCream = cream;
        if (volume < 0) {
            System.out.println("error: negative size. Defaultsize of 250 ml used");
            coffeeVol = 250;
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        return coffeeVol +"ml, " + coffeeFlav + ", " + yesCream;
     } // end toString
```

---

```
    public static int totalCups() {
         //THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE
    }
```

---

```
    public int doubleSize() {
        coffeeVol = coffeeVol*2;
        return coffeeVol;
    }


}
```

Is there a way to sum the number of coffee cups? I'm truly lost in this respect, and any help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count the number of instances of a particular class in inheritance tree, created explicitly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013349/how-to-count-the-number-of-instances-of-a-particular-class-in-inheritance-tree)

Comment: I'm not extending anything here, just calling from a different class.

Comment: Yeah but the solution should still be applicable.. the trick is to declare a static count variable and increment it in the constructor.

Comment: Did any of the answers so far solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could add a static variable to your `Coffee` class and increment it in your constructor.

Something like that:

```
public class Coffee {
    private static int numberOfCups = 0;
    private int coffeeVol;
    private String coffeeFlav;
    private boolean yesCream;

    public Coffee(int volume, String flavour, boolean cream) {
        this.coffeeFlav = flavour;
        this.coffeeVol = volume;
        this.yesCream = cream;
        if (volume < 0) {
            System.out.println("error: negative size. Defaultsize of 250 ml used");
            coffeeVol = 250;
        }
        numberOfCups++;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return coffeeVol +"ml, " + coffeeFlav + ", " + yesCream;
    } // end toString

    public static int totalCups() {
         return numberOfCups;
    }

    public int doubleSize() {
        coffeeVol = coffeeVol*2;
        return coffeeVol;
    }

    public static boolean bigger(Coffee cup1, Coffee cup2) {
        if (cup1.coffeeVol > cup2.coffeeVol) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to be precise, you should override finalize() with totalCups-- to ensure that discarded cups are not part of the total number of cups.

Comment: I'd say it depends. He wanted to have the number of instances created, not the number of instances currently in memory ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a static field and increment it every time the constructor is called.

```
    public class Coffee {

    private static int totalCups;

    // rest of the code ...

    public Coffee(int volume, String flavour, boolean cream) {
        totalCups++;
        // rest of the code...
    }

    public static int getTotalCups() {
        return totalCups;
    }
}
// rest of the code ...
```

You want to make the field and method static because it will be shared by all instances of Coffee. You want to make totalCups a private field because of data encapsulation (you do not want to allow someone to change the total number of cups, which can only be modified logically via the constructor) and then retrieve it with a public getter method (which allows you to run additional data validation)

Comment: Maybe using matching variable names to prevent compilation errors (you forgot one even after your edit)?

Comment: "totalCups has not been initialized"

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use something called an initialization block, and a static integer field to hold the current number of instances of your class. This is the best way of doing what you want, in my opinion.

```
public class Coffee
{
    // Hold the number of instances.
    private static int instances;

    // This snippet of code will run whenever one of the //
    // constructors below is called. All subclasses will //
    // automatically inherit this too, by the way. //
    {
        instances++;
    }

    // first constructor
    public Coffee() {} 
    // second constructor
    public Coffee(int Foo) {}
    // third constructor
    public Coffee(double Bar) {}

    // return the number of instances you have.
    public static int totalCups() 
    {
        return instances;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. For every instance of the `Cofee` class, `instances` field will be always `1`, as it is a non-static attribute, meaning it won't be shared among different instances of the class. Moreover, it must be `private`, so that it's not modified from outside of class `Cofee`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, apparently I stated that a static field is needed but I forgot to actually use one in the code snippet. That's besides the point I'm making though.

Comment: Your point is valid and I agree. Up voted now that you've fixed your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the #/cups ... and you also want to compare each of the cups with each other ("which cup is largest") ... then you really ought to consider using a [Collection](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaCollections/article.html).

EXAMPLE:

```
public class UsesCoffee{

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     ArrayList<Coffee> cups = new ArrayList<Coffee>();
     System.out.println("cups created: " + cups.size());

     cups.add(new Coffee(350, "mint", true));
     cups.add(new Coffee(500, "mocha", false));
     System.out.println("cups created: " + cups.size());

     Coffee biggestCup = cups.get(0);
     for (Coffee cup : cups) {
       if (cup.coffeeVol > biggestCup.coffeeVol)
         biggestCup = cup;
     }
     System.out.println("biggest cup is " + biggestCup.coffeeVol);
   } 
}
```